# iOS: Toolbar above keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolBar, and a TextBox. When I select the TextBox, the keyboard appears and the toolbar disappears (because the keyboard is in front of the toolbar).
I want to do like status update of facebook, when you select the TextBox, the Toolbar is above the keyboard:

[image: Status Facebook]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Text fields have this property called `inputAccessoryView`, that allows you to put any view on top of the keyboard. It looks like your case is pretty simple, otherwise, if you cannot use accessory view, you can look at dozens of implementations [here](http://beta.cocoapods.org/?q=on%3aios%20keyboard).

Comment: To use inputAccessoryView I have to create the toolbar dynamically?

Comment: Well, you can build your toolbar in a xib, but then connect it in code, because I don't think IB has an outlet for accessory view.

Comment: I connected the toolbar, and did this: - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView setInputAccessoryView:_toolBar];
} but still not working

Comment: Make sure your _toolBar is not nil, and you can set it even in viewDidLoad really. Take a look at http://ankushasthana.blogspot.com/2013/04/ios-input-accessory-view_8.html for visual clues

Answer (score 1):

First create a [UIToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that has your desired buttons etc...

Then all you need to do is on

```
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    toolBar *tb = [[myToolbar alloc] init]
    [textView setInputAccessoryView:tb];
}
```

if Not try this using IB Maybe (not tested)

```
myToolbarClass* myToolbar = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
loadNibNamed:@"toolbarNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
[textView setInputAccessoryView:myToolbar];
```

Comment: toolBar *tb = [[myToolbar alloc] init]
didn't understand it. I tried:  (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { [textView setInputAccessoryView:_toolBar]; } but still not working

Comment: sorry was a pretty bad Explanation. myToolbar is an example of Subclassing UIToolbar. In the subclass build your toolbar then use an instance of it above. Dmitry is also correct you could just create your UIToolbar in viewDidLoad; add UIBarButtonItems to it then just setInputAccessoryView to the Toolbar.

Comment: Sorry, Tomskiis, I'm really newbie on iOS. I already created the Toolbar using IB and connect it to the my class. So, I have to create the toolbar programmatically?

Comment: If you've got your IB connected to a class you should be able to create an instance of it as above. I don't really use nib files for stuff like this but if it's not working maybe you need to call the awakeFromNib method in your UIToolbar class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and objective tutorial.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/how-to-make-an-app-2/toolbar-animation-along-with-the-keyboard/